# How to add additional methods to autocomplete in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, java-stream

When I'm coding using IntelliJ I frequently use the auto-completion as a way of speeding up my coding, however there are certain methods that it doesn't seem to suggest. One example is `Collectors.toMap` - it will suggest `toSet`, `toColletion` and `toList` when I type `.collect` but never `toMap` which means I need to type more.

As a 1st question, can I fix this behaviour? As a more general question, can I add my own custom code to be auto completed in these types of circumstance?

Comment: Could you please provide code example where you use completion?

Comment: `list.stream().coll` I hope to have an option for populating `list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(`

Comment: Looks like a bug. Please report it to YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Answer (score 0):

One trick which helps me out every time while trying to collect the stream is having a placeholder variable with the expected type. Something like:

```java
// just a placeholder variable with proper types, which I can remove later!
Map<String, String> tempMapVariable = someCollection.stream()
       .collect(
           // here it will suggest the .toMap(...)
           Collectors.toMap(i -> i.getKey(), i -> getValue())
       );

Set<String> tempSetVariable = someCollection.stream()
       .map(SomeCollection::mapperFn)
       .collect(
           // here it will suggest the .toSet()
           Collectors.toSet()
       );
```